# Angular 2 Allow directive to perform and action at same time

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a directive which prevents a double click on the submit button:

```
import { Directive, Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, HostListener, ElementRef, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'button[type=submit]'
})
export class PreventDoubleSubmit {

  @HostBinding() disabled:boolean = false;

  @Input() valid:boolean = true;      

  @HostListener('click') 
  onClick() {
      console.log("aaa");
    this.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Of which I then use in a shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreventDoubleSubmit } from '../shared/prevent-double-submit.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PreventDoubleSubmit
    ],
    exports: [
        PreventDoubleSubmit
    ]
})
export class SharedModule{}
```

And then use this in the app.module. Any form in the app now correctly disables the button when it is clicked on the first time. However the original actions in the form now don't perform at all. It's as if the directive has taken full priority over everything and prevents anything else from happening.

I'm using the following form tag:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" class="generalForm"></form>
```

And then in the typescript I just use:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        console.log("This is the code I want to perform");
}
```

Comment: listent to submit instead of click

Comment: @JEY Hmm tried that but didn't work. Same result.

Comment: could you provide the module declaration where your component is define ?

Answer (score 0):

I used your directive with small changes

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'button[name=saveButton]'
})
export class PreventDoubleSubmit {

    @HostBinding() disabled: boolean = false;

    @Input() valid: boolean = true;

    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
        console.log("saveButton is disabled");
        this.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

then I imported it in app.module

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[...],
    declarations: [
...
PreventDoubleSubmit,
...
]
export class AppModule { }
```

Working fine with me.